# Why do some circuits work in LTspice, but not in Proteus?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, signal, simulation

Why do some circuits work in LTspice, but not in Proteus?

I was playing with my amplifier circuits in LTspice by changing the values forth and back, I had calculated. I was thinking about a special amplifier circuit and decided to omit the input signal and let the circuit work with only one DC source. The result was so, as I had configured an AC signal from DC signal.

Then I was curious, if this would work in Proteus, too. I gave a try with that and ended in ruin. It was not running in Proteus. Proteus gave me a permanent straight line of DC voltage. I was researching why this problem occurred. Some say, that LTspice had implemented a noise in DC source, therefore it should work in LTspice.

I begin mistrusting LTspice and Proteus. Can you tell me which simulation of these software is more reliable for amplification of signal processing than the other one?

Below is the circuit. The picture is from LTspice.

[image: circuit]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 916 1288
WIRE 368 -64 112 -64
WIRE 112 -48 112 -64
WIRE 112 -48 -208 -48
WIRE 112 0 112 -48
WIRE 112 0 64 0
WIRE 160 0 112 0
WIRE 64 80 64 0
WIRE 160 80 160 0
WIRE 368 160 368 -64
WIRE 64 192 64 160
WIRE 128 192 64 192
WIRE 160 192 160 144
WIRE 160 192 128 192
WIRE -208 208 -208 -48
WIRE 128 384 128 192
WIRE 528 384 128 384
WIRE 544 384 528 384
WIRE 128 448 128 384
WIRE 240 448 128 448
WIRE 128 480 128 448
WIRE 240 496 240 448
WIRE -208 528 -208 288
WIRE 64 528 -208 528
WIRE 128 608 128 576
WIRE 240 608 240 560
WIRE 240 608 128 608
WIRE -208 656 -208 528
WIRE 128 656 128 608
WIRE -208 864 -208 736
WIRE 128 864 128 736
WIRE 128 864 -208 864
WIRE 128 912 128 864
WIRE 208 912 128 912
WIRE 368 912 368 240
WIRE 368 912 208 912
WIRE 208 944 208 912
FLAG 208 944 0
FLAG 528 384 antenna
IOPIN 528 384 Out
DATAFLAG 128 288 ""
SYMBOL cap 144 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 2.2p
SYMBOL ind 48 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL voltage 368 144 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 12V
SYMBOL npn 64 480 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value BC547B
SYMBOL res -224 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res -224 640 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 470
SYMBOL res 112 640 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL cap 224 496 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 3.3p
TEXT 56 968 Left 2 !.tran 20us
TEXT -432 992 Left 2 !;ac lin 500 100Meg 130Meg
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on “not running”?

Comment: @winny Is that, what you mean? I added a line to my question. Thanks for comment.

Comment: I think you could be more straightforward with what you want. There's a whole lot of not-very-relevant detail. You have what you expect to be an oscillator, and it oscillates in LTspice, but not in Proteus. Focusing on that should make the question easier to understand - after all, this is not about amplifiers anymore. Then you can google why oscillators don't always oscillate in SPICE and there'll be plenty to read. Now, you can also wonder whether the circuit will oscillate in real life -  that's where bench results trump any simulations. You have to test a real circuit in the end. ALWAYS.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica In conclusion, I plan to obtain an oscillator to get sure the circuit is working. Thanks for comment and the answer.

Comment: To help you google for related information: *I want to ensure my oscillator always starts up*. Engineering has its own jargon and I sympathize with the need to learn this along learning the subject matter (engineering itself). It's quite a bit of work, but please don't be discouraged by that :)

Comment: I think the LTspice from time to time involves a small disturbance into solving so it help oscillators to startup.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I’ve had cases where it refuses to oscillate in LTspice but does in Proteus despite same models. Something to clearly _different_ under the hood in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I begin mistrusting LTspice and Proteus.

As you well should. With circuits that are fairly complex, you must understand how they work on your own. You should be able to say what the circuit is doing more-or-less before even trying a simulation. The simulation should be there to point to any errors in your reasoning, and to give quantitative results. Circuit engineering can be done with "simulator in the loop", but that requires some experience.

> Can you tell me which simulation of these software is more reliable for amplification of signal processing than the other one?

They are both equally good, when used correctly.

Your mistake is assuming that SPICE can always start an oscillator. Don't assume that, and instead give the oscillator a little "kick" to get it going in SPICE. You can validate reliable startup later on the bench. Or you can use SPICE to show that only the DC operating condition that supports the oscillation is stable. The other DC operating conditions where the circuit doesn't oscillate should be unstable, i.e. the circuit should "get out of them" by itself. In fancy terms, the DC phase diagram of the circuit should have only one attractor, and that DC operating point should provide enough gain to maintain the oscillation condition.

Sometimes, the only "kick" needed to get an oscillator going is to start the simulation from zero initial condition, and not from the stable DC operating point. After all, that's how the circuit will be used in practice. It doesn't just "drop into existence" at the final DC operating point. Instead, it's powered up, and the supply rail goes from 0 to nominal value over some finite time.

If this "zero initial condition (0 IC)" approach doesn't work, you can inject a low amplitude current pulse into the circuit. The pulse can go from say 10uA down to 0uA after some small fixed time on the order of the oscillation period. That way long-term, there's no current injection, and the transient from 10uA down to 0uA is what "kick-starts" the simulation. Real circuits usually are noisy enough that they get oscillating by themselves.

Now, perhaps the oscillation is unintentional, so your question is the inverse: "how to prevent this thing from oscillating, I want an amplifier, and I want to trust the simulation that tells me there's no oscillation". For that, you need to do a loop gain analysis, whether in frequency or time domain, but there's no way around it. Look at [Barkhausen stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausen_stability_criterion) and go from there. Some people (myself included) find it easier to reason about loop response in time domain rather that frequency domain, so don't think that a Bode plot is the only way to visualize things. Impulse response provides same information in time domain.

Comment: It seems, I have to obtain a good oscillator to see if circuits are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is different models:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any mention of the BC847B in the question, so why would that be the problem?

Comment: Alexander - As commented above, it seems that you used different transistors in your two simulations, which isn't part of the question. And you used QSPICE, so that's different to the question too. || Please can you (quickly) [edit] your answer to add more detail explaining *exactly* how it answers the original question. It is at risk of deletion due to the flags it is receiving and the lack of being a clear answer to the question. || As you're new here, please see the site rules in the [tour] & [help], as they differ from typical forums. TY

Comment: Alexander - I'm guessing (as we're hoping you'll add more detail to your answer) that you're implying the cause of the different behaviours described in the question, is due to different transistor models used by LTspice & Proteus, even though you didn't use either of those simulators in your answer. Is that what you are trying to say in your answer? If so, please can you edit your answer to make that clear. TY